# vue-loader interfering with custom plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack-4, webpack-plugin, webpack-loader

To preprocess some custom non-HTML tags in a `.vue` file, I used to be (Webpack 3) able to install a loader via a plugin that would convert those custom tags into valid html/js code before the vue loader would see them and fail.

```
  apply(compiler) {

    compiler.plugin('normal-module-factory', normalModuleFactory => {

      normalModuleFactory.plugin('after-resolve', (data, callback) => {
        let filename = data.resource;
        // check filename
        data.loaders.push({
          loader: path.resolve('./my-custom-loader')
        });

      }
    }
  }
```

Now with Webpack 4 and the vue-loader (v15) this doesn't seem to work any more. The `VueLoaderPlugin` seems to modify the rules (using what they call "pitcher") which causes my custom loader still to be called, but the changed output (the substitution of the non-html tags) doesn't seem to be passed into the vue-loader (`templateLoader.js`) any more.

```
class VueLoaderPlugin {
  apply (compiler) {
    ...
    // replace original rules
    compiler.options.module.rules = [
      pitcher,
      ...clonedRules,
      ...rules
    ]
```

I haven't been able to investigate this any further than the above, so would appreciate any pointers anyone may have. In essence, I try to run my customer loader before `vue-loader` to alter the `.vue` files before the vue-loader gets to process them.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the problem by moving the custom loader into the `*.vue` rule:

```
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: [
          'vue-loader',
          {loader: myCustomLoader}
        ]
      },
```

instead of using:

```
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      },
```

which is the standard way of adding `vue-loader`.